# VBA pass multiple arguments into function within for Loop

Tags: vba, function, for-loop, ms-access, foreach

I have a function which returns a stock price for a given day. If the value returned is empty then a Do Until loop decreases the date by 1 and calls the function again with the new date. Once Do Until condition is met and no price has been found, the price is set to 0.

Code snippet below illustrates how a working version of this code works:

```
Dim Date1 As Date
Dim r As Variant
Dim Price1 As Variant
Dim arg1 As Variant
Dim arg2 As Variant
Dim counter As Integer

r = Function1(arg1, arg2, Date1, Date1)
Price1 = r(0, 0)
Do Until IsEmpty(Price1) = False And counter <= 10
    Date1 = Date1 - 1
    counter = counter + 1
    r = Function1(arg1, arg2, Date1, Date1)
    Price1 = r(0, 0)
    If counter = 10 Then
        Price1 = 0
    End If
Loop
```

Now, i am trying to recreate this code so that i can pass two dates into it and retrieve two different prices for their respective days (having also gone through the Do Until routine in the case of empty results).

Thus far, I've been trying to use the 'For' loop along with various 'If' Statements to pass the arguments in the correct way but none have worked.

My latest attempt along with the Logic can be seen below:

*On iteration 1, pass Date1 into function, retrieve Price 1 and assign this to the variable PriceT.*

*On iteration 2, pass Date2 into function, retrieve Price 2 and assign this to the variable PriceTX, then Exit loop.*

```
Dim Dates(0 To 1) As Date
Dim Count As Integer
Dim counter, PriceT, PriceTX, arg1, arg2, x, y, j As Variant

For Count = 1 To 2
    If Count = 1 Then j = Date1 Else j = Date2
    x = Function1(arg1, arg2, j, j)
    y = x(0,0)
    Do Until IsEmpty(y) = False And counter <= 10
        j = j - 1
        counter = counter + 1
        x = Function1(arg1, arg2, j, j)
        y = x(0, 0)
        If counter = 10 Then
            y = 0
        End If
    Loop
    If Count = 1 Then y = PriceT Else y = PriceTX
Next
```

I would like to mention that i'm seeking a neat and highly optimized solution, i'm trying to avoid replicating the working code twice and doubling the amount of lines (though i know that would work as I've already tried it.)

I don't really understand how else to approach this. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please include the rest of your code? It's hard to tell what's going on without knowing what `Function1` is.

Comment: Hi, `function1` links to a large class module so there's too much code to post. However, there are no issues with the function and on it's own it works perfectly. The two dates that get passed into the function are simply of `Date` type and are of the form dd/mm/yyyy. The problem is the way in which the loops/if statements are structured. 
 Thanks

Comment: What type does `Function1` return? What is `x` declared as? What is `y` declared as? You pass `Function1(j, j)` into `x`, then immediately try to pass `x(0, 0)` into `y` - that makes no sense to me and I would think would throw an error, *unless* they're being declared as something specific, which I can't tell from what you're provided us.

Comment: Because you haven't provided enough information, I doubt we'll be able to help you because we can't decipher your code.

Comment: Sorry about that, hopefully the above edits help. Thank you

Comment: Please show the function. If its too long, you just show its declaration and the variable it returns.. We need to know how are declared the input and output variables to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have missed the point, but you may simply want:

```
  PriceT = func1(Date1)
  PriceTX = func1(Date2)

Function func1(j As Date) As Variant
  x = Function1(arg1, arg2, j, j)
  y = x(0, 0)
  Do Until IsEmpty(y) = False And counter <= 10
    j = j - 1
    counter = counter + 1
    x = Function1(arg1, arg2, j, j)
    y = x(0, 0)
    If counter = 10 Then
      y = 0
    End If
  Loop
  func1 = y
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I had to play around a bit with the arguments as I also needed to pass an array into the function however this has proved to be a perfect solution. Does exactly what it needs to do. In the future i'll look into functions first before thinking everything can be done with a loop!

Comment: @ go995  You're welcome.  Normal response in SO (Stack Overflow) is to "accept" the answer.